# Hide button bar in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application that needs to be on full screen mode.

[image]

I tried to use this code in my manifest,

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

but nothing happened and still the button bar (such as Home, Back and Recent Task App) was there. I need to hide them in order to totally have a full screen. Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I finally figure it out and make my activity in full screen mode.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(8);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

see [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

from API 19 later, you can use `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` flag:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

see docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Comment: @androidBoomer yes, with this approach, touching anywhere on the screen causes the navigation bar (and status bar) to reappear and remain visible. The user interaction causes the flags to be be cleared.

Comment: This is standard practice. User interaction will cause the flags to be cleared in order to enable navigation.

Comment: So what will I do in order to making it the flags not to be cleared?

Comment: @androidBoomer you can't, but you can reset the flag after a certain time

Answer (score 1):

Try to write this code before `setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);`

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

This code work to me

Comment: I'm not sure if the asker wants the bar with time, etc. hid as well.

Comment: In my code, the the task bar with the time is actually hidden. But the button bar is not...

Comment: Yes. It disappears but the buttons at the bottom did not.

Answer (score 0):

@bladefury has a good answer, but you may want to look into this as well...

You're also describing a new feature in `4.4 KitKat` called `Immersive Mode`. 
Please note that you need API 19 to test this on.

Check out the [developer documents](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)