# How to hide System UI ( Status bar) without hiding Navigation bar?

Tags: android, uinavigationcontroller

I want to hide status bar ( Syste UI ) in my application and i want to show navigation bar always. 
From android developer docs i got this code to get full screen.

```
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

it will hide navigation and status bars both.

`SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`, this flag hides the navigation bar. but i want to hide only status bar and show navigation bar always.. please tell me what flags are required to do this.

**EDIT :** I want to do this in Kindle tab (6 inch tab ).
`View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` this tag hiding both bars. but i want to hide only status bar.. show navigation bar always.

Comment: have you try this SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE instead SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana.. yes i tried both flags .. not working for my requirement .

Answer (score 0):

[image]Put below code in your manifest file for that particular activity:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
```

OR

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Style.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

     <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I want to hide only status bar. this code will hide both navigation and status bar..

Comment: i already did this code in my app. and its not hiding navigation bar.

Comment: it's hiding navigation bar also in the Jelly bean.

Comment: have you tried this.? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342514/hiding-the-status-bar-under-android-4-2-2-sdk-17

Comment: and i also test this code in jelly bean and its working fine.

Comment: screen shots.. how your code works 1. this is hiding both : http://gyazo.com/440ba8241d12349e2e5a43e02ea93044 2. when i drag from top it shows both bars : http://gyazo.com/1c171e1e297df9cb113670ab0c331fcc

Comment: then atleast mention tab in your question so that we can help you according to that.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this code,

```
public class ActivityName extends MyActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

Comment: I want to hide only status bar. this code will hide both navigation and status bar..

Comment: Still it's hiding both .. i want only status bar.. i am testing in jelly bean android device.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy whatyou are trying to achieve is not possible ...
read the link below
https://developer.android.com/samples/ImmersiveMode/index.html